# DataContractSerializer ignore properties by criteria not using IgnoreDataMemberAttribute

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

Is there any way to ignore a property on an object without using IgnoreDataMemberAttribute?

For example I want to ignore all properties which end with Id

Answer (score 0):

The use of IDataContractSurrogate lets you do custom serialization and deserialization on a per-type or per-object basis. In your case, you'd have two types A and B. A would be the original type, and B would be A without the phantom member you don't care about.

Surrogates have been around for a while, even before WCF, and their idea is simple: replacing something that is part of an object graph like A to to be serialized as part of  B (the “surrogate”).